# SMTP Response: Queued mail for delivery

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, amazon-ses

I have ruby app which uses SMTP from SES aws.
In some my log from SNS I got something like that:

```
 "delivery": {
    "timestamp": "2022-09-02T12:38:30.510Z",
    "processingTimeMillis": 1678,
    "recipients": [
        "example@mail
    ],
    "smtpResponse": "250 2.6.0 <xxxxx@eu-west-1.amazonses.com> [InternalId=xxxxx, Hostname=xxxx.prod.outlook.com] 13028 bytes in 0.065, 192.793 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery",
    "remoteMtaIp": "x.x.x.x",
    "reportingMTA": "x.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com"
}
```

}
My question is about `Queued mail for delivery`, becouse when I got this response the e-mail does not reach the end recipient.
It happens randomly, some emails arrive, some don't.
When emails arrive I got: `"smtpResponse": "250 OK (someexample@mail.com:250 2.6.0 <x-x-x-x@eu-west-1.amazon...)",`.

How can I solve it or where to look for the problem?

Comment: Do you have the proper email configuration for you domain (i.e. SPF, DKIM, DMARC)?

Comment: @stdunbar Hmm, I didn't do anything with it in my dns. 
if it was DNS fault, is it possible that one e-mails come and the other doesn't?

Comment: I'm not positive that it does but the destination (outlook.com in this case) gets to decide if they want to receive mail from you or not.  By making sure that your domain is configured to allow SES to send your improving the chances of it getting through.

Comment: The event type in your case is 'delivery' which according to aws means 'Delivery – Amazon SES successfully delivered the email to the recipient's mail server.' The response is from the recipeint's server and not the sender's. If emails are not delivered, the reason might be with the recpient's smtp server.

Comment: @Riz hi, thanks for the response, do you know something what recipeints can do to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately apart from checking spam(if deleivered to their inbox), nothing. It totally depends on their email provider.